# Comparing Dates in PL/SQL (I'm a beginner, be gentle)

Tags: sql, oracle

Relatively new to SQL, so still trying to get my head around a couple of concepts.

I have two tables, the first has a bunch of VARCHAR attributes, as well as a 'DAY' column which is in date format, and 'USAGE', a number.

The second table only has one column, 'HOLIDAY_DATE', also datatype date. As the name suggests, this is a bunch of dates corresponding to past and future holidays.

I'm trying to find 'USAGE' on days that are not holidays, by comparing 'DAY' in the first table to 'DATE' in the second. My select statement so far is:

```
SELECT DAY, USAGE
FROM FIRST_TABLE, HOLIDAYS
WHERE FIRST_TABLE.DAY, NOT LIKE HOLIDAYS.HOLIDAY_DATE
GROUP BY DAY, USAGE
ORDER BY DAY;
```

But this still seems to bring up ALL the days, including holidays. Not quite sure where to go from here.

Comment: Note that your example is *not* PL/SQL. PL/SQL is strictly for stored procedures in Oracle. Anything else is "just" SQL.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT DAY, USAGE
FROM FIRST_TABLE
WHERE FIRST_TABLE.DAY NOT in (select HOLIDAY_DATE from HOLIDAYS)
GROUP BY DAY, USAGE
ORDER BY DAY
```

Answer (score 1):

there may be other ways but you can use `subquery` concept

```
SELECT DAY, USAGE
FROM FIRST_TABLE
WHERE DAY NOT IN(Select HOLIDAY_DATE FROM HOLIDAYS)
GROUP BY DAY, USAGE
ORDER BY DAY;
```

One More thing I want to add here eventhough your query has logical issue but there is Syntaxt error also

```
WHERE FIRST_TABLE.DAY, NOT LIKE HOLIDAYS.HOLIDAY_DATE
                     ^
```

Comment: Thanks, that comma was leftover from something else I'd been trying, didn't take it out when I took out the rest.

But thank you very much for help, really appreciate it!